# How to create a common table expression with an unknown recursion depth

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I am new to CTE's and all of the examples I've seen relied on a specific, predetermined recursion depth.  My table, which has a ParentId column, will be of an unknown depth.  Could someone provide guidance on how to create a CTE in which we don't know how deep the recursion will go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `MAXRECURSION` to 0 for that. When 0 is specified, no limit is applied. See [Query Hints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) for more details and examples on `MAXRECURSION`.

Comment: I would imagine I would need to set some sort of counter to stop the CTE from processing once the bottom-most depth is reached then, right?

Comment: I don't think you don't need any counter to stop processing. It will stop processing after bottom most depth is reached.